# Using pg_restore on dump file

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I have a database on Heroku I'm trying to copy to my local machine.

I created a backup of the database by doing:

`heroku pgbackups:capture`

This create a dump file of the database which I downloaded by creating a URL link to it:

`heroku pgbackups:url b004`

But now I have a dump file and don't really know what do to with it. I tried

`pg_restore`

to restore the database but I don't know where that information went. I basically want to create a .db file out of this dump file. Is that possible?

Ultimately my end goal is to access this database -- so if another method of copying the db is better, I'm fine with that that.

Comment: hang on - you've got a sqlite3 db on Heroku and you're using pgbackups to back it up??? Please clarify, I don't think you're using sqlite on Heroku.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that Heroku converts sqlite3 databases to PostgreSQL during the push. So it's a PostgreSQL database that I guess I'm working with.

Comment: Install postgres locally and use that. If you are on OS X try http://postgresapp.com

Comment: Thanks Will I'm going to try this now.

Answer (score 3):

Heroku does not allow you to use sqlite files, as they have a read only file system. But you can use Django to dump the data from Heroku into a JSON file via the [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model) command, and them import that into your local dev environment.

Because it can be difficult to run commands that generate files on the web server using `heroku run`, I suggest you instead install [django smuggler](https://github.com/semente/django-smuggler), which makes this operation a point and click affair in admin.

[image]

Comment: Ok I'm trying this now. I did the dumpdata on Heroku. But now, how do I get that off of heroku and onto my local machine?

Comment: That's why I suggested django smuggler, it gives you the dump file right in the browser as a file download.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should install postgres in your local machine.

[PostgreSQL cheat sheet for django beginners](http://od-eon.com/blogs/calvin/postgresql-cheat-sheet-beginners/)

Then, import your dump file with pg_restore command:

```
pg_restore -d yournewdb -U yournewuser --role=yournewuser /tmp/b001.dump
```

Thats all, your data is now cloned from your heroku app.