# How do I database off Heroku to my local machine? I have a Django app (not Rails)

Tags: python, database, django, heroku

How do I get my database off Heroku? I'm trying to figure out how to sync with my local machine.

I easily found instructions for a rails app, but not Django.

Answer (score 1):

While convenient, using taps may not replicate your data exactly and may run into errors for larger transfers. To import or export data from your production system, we highly recommend using pgbackups instead. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups

Comment: Ok if that's the case, then could you take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806979/using-pg-restore-on-dump-file. I wasn't sure what to do with the data once I did get it.

Answer (score 0):

The heroku cli provides the "db" command to move your data between your local machine and heroku.

See their help: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps

And their blog post from a couple years ago: http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/18/push_and_pull_databases_to_and_from_heroku/